# Does malloc assigns memory to custom struct's properties?

Tags: c, malloc, typedef

I've been working on some C projects and was wondering if I create a custom structure, for example, `Student`, define a variable of the custom structure type, and allocate memory to it using malloc, does it also allocate memory for variables' properties separately or are they all kept in the same space? if yes, will there be any difference if I allocate memory using malloc separately for every property?

For example:

```
typedef struct { 
    unsigned int ID; 
    char *first_name; 
    char *last_name;
    int num_grades; 
    float *grades;
    unsigned short int days_absent; 
    char *memo;
} Student;

int main() {

    // Declare students array
    Student *students = NULL;
    int students_size = 0;

    // Allocate memory for students array
    students = (Student *) malloc(sizeof(Student));
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That allocates enough memory for the struct, which includes enough memory for `ID`, `first_name`, etc and all padding requirements.

Note that while it allocates memory for the pointer `first_name`, it doesn't allocate a buffer to hold the name. It just allocates memory for `first_name`, a pointer. If you want memory in which to store the names, you will need to allocate it.

If the struct had a `char first_name[40];` field, it would be a different story. To allocate enough memory for `first_name`, it needs to allocate enough memory for an array of 40 `char` instead of enough for a pointer. This does provide a space in which a string could be stored.

Comment: Interesting. So what would be the case if we had a `char first_name[40];` field?

Comment: This is a good answer! You can check this page for more details on how C allocates memory for structures: https://fresh2refresh.com/c-programming/c-struct-memory-allocation/

Comment: If you had `char first_name[40];` then it will allocate memory to store this array of characters unlike before where you just declared a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't. It allocates uninitialized memory for the number of `char`s you want - which is usually a calculation based on `sizeof`s.

If you want it to allocate memory to store values that your `struct` has pointers to, you'll have to add that after having allocated the memory for the `struct`.

You'll also have to "go backwards" when you `free` such a `struct`.

Example:

```
typedef struct {
    char *data;
} foo;

foo *foo_create() {
    foo *retval = malloc(sizeof *retval ); // try allocation
    if(retval == NULL) return NULL;        // check that it worked
    retval->data = malloc(10) ;            // allocate something for a member
    if(retval->data == NULL) {             // check that it worked
        free(retval);                      // oh, it didn't, free what you allocated
        return NULL;                       // and return something to indicate failure
    }
    return retval;                         // all successful
}

void foo_free(foo *elem) {
    if(elem != NULL) {                     // just a precaution
        free(elem->data);                  // free the member's memory
        free(elem);                        // then the memory for the object
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Does it also allocate memory for variables' properties separately

No.  After allocating for `students`, allocate for `students->first_name`, `students->last_name`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> does it also allocate memory for variables' properties separately or are they all kept in the same space?

No.  `malloc()` is given a size to indicate how much contiguous memory to allocate, and it returns a pointer pointing to it... `malloc()` knows nothing about what you are going to do with the pointer.  When you assign it to a pointer variable to `Student` type is, somehow, dressing a bunch of memory with structure.  But the `char *` fields that you have defined inside (or if you have other fields pointing to other structured data) those have to be allocated separately (or ask for more memory to allocate them all in the same returned segment, but this requires practice and knowledge of the alignment issues that arise from it)